# Configure SCM URL in Jenkins job instead of Workflow script

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have written a workflow script which builds our project. Inside the `node`-block I checkout our sources from git:

```
node('nodeA') {
  git url: 'https://github.com/foo/bar.git'
  ...
}
```

The workflow script itself is part of the source code. Now different developers have different forks of the git repo. Therefore the URL is different and I would like to get rid of the hard-coded URL in the script.

Is it possible to specify the Git repo URL in the Jenkins job configuration? And how gets the actual `node` the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the *Workflow: Multibranch* plugin (currently 1.9-beta-1, on the experimental update center), in which case the Git configuration is on the job and your script merely runs

```
checkout scm
```

There is not currently a branch source handling multiple forks (or pull requests), but this is a possible integration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the Workflow: Multibranch plugin. Does it depend on newer Jenkins version than mine (1.609.1) because in the Workflow-job config where I set the Groovy CPS DSL there is no Save-button!?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Thanks to your [blog post](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2015/08/workflow-19-and-multibranch-beta.html) I have got this working!

Answer (score 2):

Another more manual possibility is to make the job parameterized, and use the same parameter name in both places. So if you defined a string parameter `GIT_URL`, specify `$GIT_URL` in the remote repository location in the job’s visual configuration (assuming you are using *Groovy CPS DSL from SCM*), and in the script use

```
git GIT_URL
```

Then each person triggering the job must define the location of their fork. (Or you could have the parameter include just the fork name, etc.)

Comment: Thanks also for this answer! But unfortunately `$GIT_URL` is not replaced by its contents: `Fetching upstream changes from ${GIT_URL}`

Comment: Use `git GIT_URL` from Groovy as I wrote originally, not `git ${GIT_URL}` (possibly a syntax error) or `git '$GIT_URL'` or `git '${GIT_URL}'` (deliberately unsubstituted strings). You _could_ use `git "$GIT_URL"` or `git "${GIT_URL}"` (substituted string) but that would be silly in this case. If the parameter is actually `GIT_REPO_NAME` rather than a full URL, you could use for example `git "git@github.com:yourorg/${GIT_REPO_NAME}.git"`.

Comment: What I meant is that I was not able to use the variable in the *Groovy CPS DSL from SCM* config section of the job, see [this image](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAspUJpUxkVF-b0R5ZLwTBU0OhkjPfFwTpoB/image.png).

Comment: I see. Sounds like a bug though I am not sure if in Workflow or the Git plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use git SCM to achieve this.

For using git scm in jenkins you should install 2 plugins.

[Git](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) and [Git client](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin)

Install git client plugin before installing git plugin.

Comment: you can pass your git repo url and branch

Comment: I know how to configure a job to use git. In Workflow scripts the initial git checkout is done on the master. The build nodes (slaves) need to get this information.

Comment: thenpass your node as parameter by using NodeLabel plugin